# Passing state to child component using .map function

Tags: reactjs

I am making a basic page which displays the workstations connected to users. 
I have a component which then calls another component in a .map function however when trying to update the parent component state it does not seem to update.

The best way I can show this is through the demonstration of my code which is stated below. (these are in the same file at the moment so multiple export statements are not currently needed)

Below is my parent component this calls a .map function which then maps all the workstations into drop down button using a separate component.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Modal,DropdownButton,Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";

class DisplayQuestions extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { questions: [], QuestionsAnswer: [], workstations: [] , selectedWorkStation: ""};
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  }
  // sets the questions form sql into state for questions
  getItems() {
    fetch("/user-questions")
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({ questions: results.recordset });
      }); 

  }


   getWorkStations() {
    var user = window.localStorage.getItem("User");
    if (user) {
      fetch(`/profile-work-station-detailss/${user}`)
        .then(recordset => recordset.json())
        .then(results => {
          this.setState({ workstations: results.recordset });
          console.log(this.state.workstations) 
        });
    }  
  } 

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      questions: this.getItems(),
       WorkStations :this.getWorkStations()
    });
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      QuestionID: this.QuestionID,
      QuestionsAnswer: this.state.QuestionsAnswer,
      QuestionSeverity: this.state.QuestionsSeverity
    };

    try {
      fetch("/Question-Response", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log("Success:", data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    } catch (error) {}
  }
  refresh() {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  render() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(this.state.questions);
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <u>Desk Assessment</u>
        </h3>

        <ul>
          <button
            disabled
            className="btn btn-secondary"
            style={{ float: "left " }}
          >
            Desk Assessment
          </button>  
          <Link to="./user-history">
            <button className="btn btn-secondary" style={{ float: "left " }}>
              View History
            </button>
          </Link>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////          

//Within this part of the code is where I am struggling
//This maps the workstations which display fine however last line of this section it tries to display //the workstation mapped. This is updated through the workstation component. 

<DropdownButton style ={{float : "right"}}  id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Select Workstation Location">
{this.state.workstations &&
              this.state.workstations.map(function(workstations, index) { 
                return (
                  <div >
                     <WorkStationSelecter workstations = {workstations}> </WorkStationSelecter>
                  </div>
                );
              })}</DropdownButton> 

<br/>
<br/>          
            <h2 className = "jumbotron">Desk Location Selected : {this.state.selectedWorkStation}</h2>

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            {this.state.questions &&
              this.state.questions.map(function(questions, index) {
                return (
                  <div >


                    <Questions questions={questions}></Questions>

                  </div>
                );
              })}

        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplayQuestions;
```

Within this component I am trying to update the parent state however nothing appears in this does not appear in the selected workstation header.
Within the selectWorkStation it updates this state and displays in the alert. How come this is not updated to the higher component to display the workstation picked.

```
class WorkStationSelecter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = { ...props,    };
    this.selectWorkStation = this.selectWorkStation.bind(this)
  }

selectWorkStation(e)
{
  e.preventDefault()

 this.state.selectedWorkStation = this.state.workstations.DeskLocation
 alert(this.state.selectedWorkStation)



}
  render() {
      return (
        <>
        <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.selectWorkStation}>{this.state.workstations.DeskLocation} </Dropdown.Item>
        <button>{this.state.selectedWorkStation}</button>

      </>
      );

    }
  }
```

Comment: First of all, you are mutating the state of your ```WorkStationSelecter``` component, which is an anti-pattern. Second, you are mutating your *child* component's state, not parent. If you want to change the state of the parent you can pass a handler to the child and call it there.

Comment: What do you mean by mutation the workstation selector? Is this as I have passed down the state using props ?

Comment: ```this.state.selectedWorkStation = this.state.workstations.DeskLocation```
This is the mutation I mentioned.